# Can you run the Python module Subprocess from App Engine standard environment?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, subprocess

Can you run the Python module Subprocess in Standard App Engine on Google Cloud Platform?

I have a Flask web app I would like to deploy but it involves the Subprocess module, which calls some batch scripts. The batch scripts execute crucial CL commands for which there is currently no Python API so I cannot think of an easy workaround for removing the dependence on Subprocess.

Will I need to deploy this on Flexible App Engine instead to be able to run the batch files?

Any guidance would be helpful, I couldn't find an explicit answer in the GCP documentation but some pointers on where to look would be brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: App Engine Standard does not support subprocess. I am not sure about Flexible. However, you are assuming that there is a User Environment Shell. That is not a good idea. I would use Cloud Run instead where you can control everything about the container.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is doable with the limitation that it has to complete within the request handling. Did you look at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#background_threads ?

"Background threads

Python 3 in the App Engine standard environment has no sandbox limitations so you are free to create threads or processes that live outside of the request environment. Threads and processes can be spawned using Python's built-in threading and multiprocessing features. However note that new threads or processes may not run after the inbound request is served."

Answer (score 0):

IDK what is purpose of your script but, on app engine STD and FLEX Is possible to run subprocess, maybe you need to create a FLEX custom runtime for add the necessary Linux dependencies for your bash script [how to build a custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).

I tried this example code on GAE FLEX/STD ENV

app.yaml [FLEX]

```
runtime: python
env: flex
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.7

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

app.yaml [STD]

```
runtime: python37

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.0.2
gunicorn
```

main.py

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    import subprocess
    process = subprocess.run(['ls','-lha'], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    output = process.stdout
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```